# Не работает WebSocket при публикации в IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, iis-10

Всем привет. При публикации проекта на IIS у меня перестал работать WebSocket.
Перед публикацией я добавил WebSocket в "Роли и компоненты". Он включен в конфигурации в IIS.
На дебаге на собственной машине он у меня отлично работает.

Скриншот сети на IIS
[image: Скриншот сети на IIS]

Скриншот сети у меня в дебаге
[image: Скриншот сети у меня в дебаге]

Answer (score 0):

В результате оказалось что порт который использовался в дебаге на kestrel для соединения с WebSocket-ом менялся для релиз версии на другой.